# Generate phoenix database diagram

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there a similar tool like Django graph_models to generate a phoenix webapp database diagram?

```
python manage.py graph_models
```

[image]

Comment: You can probably use database specific tools, like pgAdmin or DataGrip or whatever. It's a bit different but still something.

Comment: You also need to be careful not to conflate `Phoenix` with `Ecto`. `Ecto` is the database interface layer.  You can have database access code without ever having `Phoenix`.

Comment: Which database are you using under your Phoenix instance?  Please add that information to your question.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough if you know the reference Django graph_models. Database type is irrelevant like it is irrelevant for graph_models, just being a class diagram is obvious it's a sql database.

Comment: Ok, then I think the answer to your question is that you're out of luck. There is no such thing that I know of in Elixir.  I was asking about the underlying DB because you're far more likely to find a DB specific tool to do this (as @JustMichael was sort of implying).

Comment: Yes I will try with a database tool but was wondering if there is a mix tool I could use.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering this too. Since there is no Elixir/Ecto specific solution,  I found two reasonable options:

- https://dbeaver.io/ - a tool to create your ERD based on the DB alone - it is actually pretty awesome and quick. I chose this option.
- https://dbdiagram.io/ - Consider drawing your own.